# SQL query formatting in Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I want to to query my Oracle DB, but it's not working. I think i'm missing something in formatting but unable to figure out.
If i execute the same query in SQL developer, it's returning me results. But in Python it's giving 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax.' error.

```
import os
import cx_Oracle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('host', '1521', service_name='S1') 
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'dev_user', password='Welcome', dsn=dsn_tns) 


reportid_count = []
count_ID =  []

c = conn.cursor()

query = 'select distinct (LTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ID, '[0-9]{3,}'), '0')) as ReportID,count(ID) from dev_user.RECORD_TABLE  group by ID'
c.execute(query) 


#loop through the rows fetched and store the records as arrays.
for row in c:
    reportid_count.append(row[0] + ',' + str(row[1]))
    count_ID.append(row[1])

for s in reportid_count:
    print(s)
```

Comment: What is the error you get in Python?

Comment: Database is in localhost, error is- SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: There is something wrong wrong with your quoting. The first quoted string is `'select distinct (LTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ID, '` so I expect the parser complains at everything after it, starting at `[0-9]{3,}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Python side, you need to remove embedded quotes.  Try using:

```
query = """select distinct (LTRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(ID, '[0-9]{3,}'), '0')) as ReportID,count(ID) from dev_user.RECORD_TABLE  group by ID"""
```

Comment: This has solved the problem. Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 0):

IF you're using `GROUP BY`, you don't have to use `DISTINCT` because the former already makes sure you'll get distinct result. Also, you'd probably want to group by the whole select expression (`ltrim`...), not just `id`, i.e.

```
SELECT ltrim(regexp_substr(id, '[0-9]{3,}'), '0') AS reportid,
       COUNT(id)
FROM dev_user.record_table
GROUP BY ltrim(regexp_substr(id, '[0-9]{3,}'), '0')
```

---

Finally, you said

> in Python it's giving error.

*Which* error?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. This is the error i'm getting.

Comment: Tried with the same, SyntaxError: invalid syntax.error is appearing.

Comment: Is there, by any chance, error code? Something like ORA-01234 or PLS-01234 or similar? Because, SELECT statement itself looks OK and works properly in my Oracle 11gXE database. Perhaps you could just remove username from the FROM clause so that it looks "FROM record_table" as you're connected as DEV_USER anyway.